# issue with converting excel formula to java

Tags: java, math

Hi i am new to java can anyone help me to convert this formula to java code?

```
=ROUNDUP(POWER(4*B18/PI(),1/3)*100,0)
```

So far, I have this code:

```
(((4*variable)/3.142)*0.34)*100;
```

sorry for asking basic question

Comment: Sure we can do it. But first, what have you tried?

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking a basic question. But be sorry for not attempting.

Comment: (((4*variable)/3.142)*0.34)*100;

Comment: I believe Java has a MATH.Pi constant. so 'Pi' is taken care of. please do a little more code-efforts

Comment: I would highly recommend downloading (or at least bookmarking) [the java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  The class `java.lang.Math` has all the methods you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double multiplies =8 * 4;
System.out.println(Math.floor(Math.pow( multiplies/ Math.PI, 1.0/3)*100.0));

double multiplies =8 * 4;
System.out.println(Math.ceil(Math.pow( multiplies/ Math.PI, 1.0/3)*100.0));

double multiplies =8 * 4;
System.out.println(Math.round(Math.pow( multiplies/ Math.PI, 1.0/3)*100.0));
```

depending on your usage you can use this three methods

Comment: thanks suganthan you ceil suggestion worked exactly in my java app code

Answer (score 6):

In its raw (and ugly) form, it should be something like this:

```
static double yourFormula(double b18) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.pow(4.0 * b18 / Math.PI, 1.0/3) * 100.0);
}
```

EDIT: As noted by @Teepeemm, [`Math#cbrt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cbrt%28double%29) already calculates the cube root of a number. So the formula should be

```
static double yourFormula(double b18) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.cbrt(4.0 * b18 / Math.PI) * 100.0);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `Math.ceil()` instead of `Math.round()`.

Comment: Not to be picky, for clarity `1.0/3.0`

Comment: @Emmentaler `1.0/3` is just fine :).

Comment: Strange that the answer lacks output for `excel` issue. And everyone upvotes. See the post title.

Comment: @Ravinder what do you mean?

Comment: She must be using POI and needs a related answer

Comment: @Ravinder I guess I understand what you mean. AFAICS OP wants/needs to emulate this formula in his/her Java code. OP never asked how to read and evaluate this formula from an Excel file using Java.

Comment: Note that `Math.pow(x,1.0/3)` is equivalent to `Math.cbrt(x)`.

Comment: She is pretty new to SO and such posts. And hence might have not thought what she actually asked. Otherwise her query already have the same answer you have posted.

Comment: @Teepeemm didn't know about the existence of that method.

Comment: @Ravinder again, AFAICS (even by OP's question state) he/she tries to convert the formula to use it in Java. If you don't think so, post a comment in OP's question to clarify this.

Comment: @Ravinder This question is the usual "I know language X so I will use it to explain the concept I want, but I want it in language Y" language X actually has nothing to do with the question